# Find length of list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists and wish to find the length of each list. The list of lists is called `GroupedLists` and each contains 2 columns.

```
[[1]]
          preds     ground_truth
21528         1            1
14033         1            0
3770          1            1
16734         1            1
20867         1            0
26342         1            1
687           1            1
7501          1            1
15543         1            1
13239         1            0
3403          1            1

[[2]]
          preds ground_truth
5278          1            1
4745          1            1
12622         1            0
26877         1            1
441           1            1
20626         1            1

[[3]]
          preds ground_truth
7431          1            1
16675         1            1

[[4]]
[1]       preds ground_truth
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I have tried both `length` and `nrow` using the following format but neither have given the incorrect count.

```
for (list in GroupedList){
  print(length(list))
}
```

I need the output to be able to check and print the length of each list individually. The reason for this is to be able to use the length of the list in a condition like this:

```
for (list in GroupedList){
  if(length(list) > 0){
     print(list)}
}
```

Could someone show me how to count the elements in individual lists.

Comment: Try `length(list[[1]]) > 0` or `nrow(list) > 0` in the `if` condition instead of `length(list) > 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this approach. You can use `lapply()` as you have a list and the bind the results with `do.call()` and `rbind()`:

```
#Data
List <- list(structure(list(preds = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("21528", "14033", 
"3770", "16734", "20867", "26342", "687", "7501", "15543", "13239", 
"3403")), structure(list(preds = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("5278", 
"4745", "12622", "26877", "441", "20626")), structure(list(preds = c(1L, 
1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("7431", 
"16675")), structure(list(preds = integer(0), ground_truth = integer(0)), row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

The code:

```
#Obtain dim
O <-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(List,function(x) dim(x)[1])))
#Format
O$List <- rownames(O)
O <- O[,c(2,1)]
names(O)[2]<-'count'
rownames(O)<-NULL
```

Output:

```
  List count
1    1    11
2    2     6
3    3     2
4    4     0
```

**Update:** Here another approach using `for()`

```
#Data
List2 <- list(l1 = list(structure(list(preds = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("21528", 
"14033", "3770", "16734", "20867", "26342", "687", "7501", "15543", 
"13239", "3403"))), l2 = list(structure(list(preds = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("5278", 
"4745", "12622", "26877", "441", "20626"))), l3 = list(structure(list(
    preds = c(1L, 1L), ground_truth = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("7431", 
"16675"))), l4 = list(structure(list(preds = integer(0), ground_truth = integer(0)), row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame")))
```

The code:

```
#Create empty list to save results
elist <- list()
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(List2))
{
  #Check dim
  if(dim(List2[[i]][[1]])[1]>0)
  {
    df <- data.frame(name=names(List2[i]),count=dim(List2[[i]][[1]])[1])
    elist[[i]] <- df
  }
}
#Now bind
O <- do.call(rbind,elist)
```

Output:

```
  name count
1   l1    11
2   l2     6
3   l3     2
```

Comment: @geds133 Would not be the same, if after obtaining dimensions you filter out those with zero?

Comment: I can't understand where anything I defined is in your answer. Also with this answer am I still able to keep the list number?

Comment: Also, this does keep the list name and count the variables, however I don't understand how I can use this new output conditionally to edit the original list of lists.

Comment: @geds133 I have added an update, please check, final output is a dataframe then you can take the values from it to do other tasks.

Comment: Computer is down will check when back up.

Answer (score 2):

A short version:

```
 sapply(GroupedList, nrow)
```

Comment: Or `Map(nrow,GroupedList)`

Comment: for tidyverse's map function to work, you need the vector of lists to go first and then the nrow function map(GroupedList, nrow)